# How can I get rid of hours minutes and seconds from a mail sent by a js

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-docs

I've added a script in google sheets that will send me a reminder depending some start date values.
I receive this nice email, but I only want to keep the date without time and time zone.

The campaign will start in 8 days (Fri Apr 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)).

What should I do?

Comment: Can you please post the code you used to do this? Examples of what you have & what you've tried, will help...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how Google Spreadsheets work, but you can do:

```
new Date(my_date_string).toDateString();
```

to convert a date into something more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ICC.Utils.formatCalendarDate = function (dateTime) {
return moment.utc(dateTime).format('LL');
};
```